# How to avoid too many queries in Flows

Tags: visual-workflow, error, loop

I have a complex requirement that iterates over 277 records. I have achieved it using scheduled flows.

For each of the 277 records, I need to automatically create related records, which I have done using loops. As expected, I get the "Too many SOQL queries: 101" error, is there a way to overcome this?

Update:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes. What you should do is the same as you'd do in a trigger. Get the list of elements, loop over each item, then update the collection. Here's what that looks like:

[image: Example Flow]

This is, of course, a Visual Flow, but the same rules would apply for autolaunched flows as well. Query, create or update records in memory, then commit all changes.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but the flow I have added in the question is the MVP, whereas the actual use case is more complex than that. I have found out that using "Pause" element to make it an asynchronous flow works.

Answer (score 0):

Since my use case is a scheduled flow, the following worked. The idea is to make it asynchronous by adding a Pause element.

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000COJ1QAO